# fix a formula against targets move in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am making a simple Expense report with columns as shown in [image: my basic sheet]

The formula @ D3 and on is D3 = `=D2-B3`

the problem comes when, sometimes, i need to feed in a previous dates,
then i am required to move/insert a row in the Range A1:C#!
this result in shifting the values of B# in Column D ... formulas

lookie result:
[image]

Even if i manually enter `= $D$2 - $B$3` for the entire Column D,
when i move B3 to B4... the D formula gets messed up.

How can i fix the formulas to always be `= D[previous row] - B[current row]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in D3 and fill down.

```
=INDEX(D:D, ROW()-1)-INDEX(B:B, ROW())
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to indirectly reference the cells using `INDIRECT` function like this:

```
=INDIRECT("D"&(ROW()-1))-INDIRECT("B"&ROW())
```

The concatenated text string "D" and the output of `ROW` function inside the parentheses form a reference-like string (i.e. D3, D4, D5, etc.) that is evaluated by `INDIRECT` function to display their values. Very useful if you'd like to use it in such a way as you describe it. Use sparingly, though as it is a volatile function and could be slow in large workbooks.

Hope this helps..

---

References:

[INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)